# Distance calculation using multiple waypoints in android

Tags: android, android-maps

I have used below code with map its working fine. But when i use same code without map its showing wrong distance calculation. In map i have used drawn path for distance calculation. But drawing path it showing wrong distance. Please help me.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject zc = result.getJSONObject(i);
                Double lat = zc.getDouble("lat");
                Double lng = zc.getDouble("lng");
                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                points.add(latLng);

            }

            Log.e("Before filter", "" + points);

            Object[] st = points.toArray();
            for (Object s : st) {
                if (points.indexOf(s) != points.lastIndexOf(s)) {
                    points.remove(points.lastIndexOf(s));
                }
            }

            //System.out.println("Distinct List "+points);
            Log.e("After filter", "" + points);

            double distancess = SphericalUtil.computeLength(points);
            double DisKM = distancess * 0.001;
            double DisinKM = roundTwoDecimals(DisKM);

           // Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, String.valueOf(DisKM) + "KM", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Log.e("DISTANCE", "" + DisinKM);
```

Comment: it might be because map calculates distances by the road, and without maps you calculate distances straight between the points

Comment: Am doing same, but showing wrong distance.